# Why does the CSS go crazy when I use number-range?

Tags: jquery, datatables

When using the column filter plugin for Jquery Datatables. I am trying to filter by number-range the css gets out of whack.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="activeProjects">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Project Number</th>
                <th>Market</th>
                <th>Project Type</th>
                <th>Completion Date</th>
                <th>Square Footage</th>
                <th>Architect</th>
                <th>Manager</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><a href></a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="clear">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#activeProjects').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": false,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "../api/Project/GetAll/",
                "dataSrc": ""
            },
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                {
                    "aTargets": [1],
                    "mRender": function(data) {
                        return '<a href="ExistingProject?jobNumber=' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                    }
                }
            ],
            "sPlaceHolder": "head:before",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "ProjectName" },
                { "data": "ProjectNumber" },
                { "data": "MarketName" },
                { "data": "ProjectTypeName" },
                { "data": "DateCompleted" },
                { "data": "SquareFoot" },
                { "data": "ProjectManager" },
                { "data": "ProjectArchitect" }
            ],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            }).columnFilter({
                aoColumns: [
                { type: "text", },
                { type: "text" }, 
                { type: "text" }, 
                { type: "number-range" }, 
                { type: "text" }, 
                { type: "text" }, 
                { type: "text" }, 
                { type: "text" } 
                ]
            });
    });

    $('#clear').click(function() {
        location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

When I do this the css looks like this:

[image: Image of the problem]

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Have you inspected the elements with your browser's dev tools?

Comment: Yes, they look like they should. There is no crazy css being added and there is nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: browser? are you using?

Comment: @CayceK I am using Chrome, I have checked it in IE, and FireFox as well and I get the same result

Comment: are those floated?? the From and To fields?

Comment: all it is that I see is that the From / To form fields are not fitting in the correct table spot and just floating above verything. the 0.000 has nothing to do with the fields themselves. That is just the text associated to the row to the left.

Comment: @CayceK that is correct, any idea how to resize them. If I try and resize the TH or the TD then the boxes just extend the length of the parent

Comment: My suggestion would be to split them into two more fields. `From` and `To` as the header and then put `(sqft)` so you can do `From (sqft)` | `To (sqft)` that should help. And then maybe have the sqft number show twice? Idk how that would be best. But the only other option is to add a field col=5 which might work, but I do not think that is the best route. (Didn't want to post an answer as I do not believe this is an appropriate solution).